# Why does my recursive function using pointers works when called once, but not when I re-run my program?

Tags: pointers, recursion

I have been asked to implement a function "fold" for an assessment, which takes a double table, its int size, a double initial value and a double function as arguments. It should return a double by cumulatively applying the function to the elements of the table, starting with the initial value.

For example, with the table {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}, the initial value 10.0 and the adding function, it should return :

((((((((((10.0 + 1.0) + 1.0) + 2.0) + 2.0) + 3.0) + 3.0) + 4.0) + 4.0) + 5.0) + 5.0) = 40.0

I know I could have done iteratively but for some reasons I decided to be an elegant programmer and use recursion. Here is my program :

```
double fold(double* tab, int size, double init, double func(double, double)){
double result = func(func(init, *tab), *tab);
if (size > 0){
    return fold(tab + 1, size - 1, result, func);
}
return result;
```

}

And here is my test :

```
int main(){
double init = 10.0;
double table[5] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
double result = fold(table, 5, init, &add);
printf("Expected: %f, Result: %f", 40.0, result);
```

}

When run once, it gives me the correct result, but when I re-run it it explodes to huge values. Does anyone know where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

When size == 0, you reference table[5], which is random memory just off then of table[].   Change `if (size > 0) {` to `if (size > 1) {`.

Comment: Jesus Christ, it was that simple. Thanks so much !